# Capacitor - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to implement notifications with Capacitor FCM plugin in my Android app. However, when running the following code in Android Studio, I get this error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined".

I'm using Ionic 5 with Vue 3.

App.vue

```
async pushInit() {
      const fcm = new FCM();

      alert("...");
      try {
        PushNotifications.addListener("registrationError", (error) => {
          console.log(`error on register ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        }),
          PushNotifications.addListener(
            "pushNotificationReceived",
            (notification) => {
              console.log(`notification ${JSON.stringify(notification)}`);
            }
          ),
          PushNotifications.addListener(
            "pushNotificationActionPerformed",
            async (notification) => {
              console.log("notification succeeded");
            }
          ),
          PushNotifications.register();
        const fcmToken = await fcm.getToken();
        alert(fcmToken);
        console.log("token:" + fcmToken);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
```

I already ran npx cap sync android.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by the following steps:

Added in data return:

```
fcm: new FCM()
```

Added the following in Android Studio:
MainActivity.java: `import com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin;` and then inside the init callback `add(FCMPlugin.class);`